# SQL: Retrieve all records where has all joined

Tags: sql, oracle

Sorry, couldn't think of a better title.

I have 3 tables in Oracle XE. An EMPLOYEE table a PROJECT table and a WORK_ON table. An EMPLOYEE can WORK_ON many PROJECTs. I am trying to get the employee name who is working on **all** the projects.

```
EMPLOYEE Table
Emp_ID   EMP_Name
1        Esther
2        Peter
3        Joan
4        Roger
5        Liam

PROJECT Table
Project_ID
1
2
3

WROKS_ON Table
Emp_ID       Project_ID
1            3
2            1
2            2
2            3
3            1
3            2
4            1
4            2
4            3
```

Given the fields my result should be **Peter** and **Roger**.

Started with the following, but got stuck:

```
SELECT EMP_NameLOYEE.E_NAME
FROM EMP_NameLOYEE INNER JOIN 
(PROJECT INNER JOIN WROKS_ON ON PROJECT.Project_ID = WROKS_ON.Project_ID) ON 
EMP_NameLOYEE.Emp_ID = WROKS_ON.Emp_ID
WHERE WROKS_ON.Project_ID In (SELECT DISTINCT Project_ID FROM PROJECT);
```

Obviously this retrieves all the names of the employees that are working on each project duplicated, but not exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leave the project table out of it.

```
SELECT e.emp_id, COUNT(project_id)
FROM employee e
INNER JOIN works_on wo ON wo.emp_id = e.emp_id
GROUP BY e.emp_id
HAVING COUNT( project_id ) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM project);
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f751b0/3)

Comment: I like this. Much simpler. I would only really change the *select* to just `SELECT e.E_NAME`. Been going over it way more than I needed to. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to generate all combinations of employees and projects with a `cross join` and `left join` the works table and check for row counts for each e_name.

```
SELECT e.E_NAME
FROM EMPLOYEE e
CROSS JOIN PROJECT p
LEFT JOIN WORKS_ON w ON p.Project_ID = w.Project_ID and e.emp_id=w.emp_id
GROUP by e.E_NAME
HAVING COUNT(*)=COUNT(w.project_id)
```